# 1. Reference Error: Function not defined. 2. Array not getting passed into a function

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I have a very basic jsfiddle. I am getting reference error for the function. I fail to understand the reason for the same. Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/akshaysuri/xxmq8e3m/

JavaScript:

```
function f1(){
    var str = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff";
    var strArr = str.split(",");
    f2(strArr,strArr.length);
}

function f2(arr,len){
  alert(len);
  alert(arr);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
 <button type="button" onclick="f1()">Click Me!</button> 
 </body>
```

The real problem I am facing in my application is that when I pass the array to f2, only first element is passed to f2 and not the entire array. I was trying to test it using a jsfiddle but first I need to get the reference error resolved.

Comment: In the top right of the javascript panel -> click on the settings icon -> Change `Load Type` to a `No Wrap` value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3gwyu9cf/1/

Comment: there are lot of duplicates - https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow%20jsfiddle%20function%20not%20defined - you can also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692921/why-does-jsfiddle-throw-error-that-function-is-not-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding it to the window like so

```
window.f1 = function(){
    var str = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff";
    var strArr = str.split(",");
    f2(strArr,strArr.length);
}
```

As the fiddle is set to onLoad, it wraps your code in `window.onload=function(){/*code*/}`, meaning that the scope is no longer global.

> The real problem I am facing in my application is that when I pass the
>   array to f2, only first element is passed to f2 and not the entire
>   array.

The array is being passed, it's just that alert() formats it exactly as your original string is shown, which is misleading. Try alerting arr[0] or arr[1].

Comment: Thanks, it is working with even f1 = function(){ .... }. Can you explain the reason behind this? Why it failed to work with function f1(){....}?

Comment: As Arun said, the load type was set to onLoad. On load wraps your code in a `window.onload=function(){}`, meaning your functions are no longer defined in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

**It's a scope problem, Joseph is in the correct way.**

**EXPLANATION**

If you use the window variable you can force the global scope.
However you algo can change the declaration order to correct your code.

```
 <body>
 <script>
 function f1(){
    var str = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff";
    var strArr = str.split(",");
    f2(strArr,strArr.length);
}

function f2(arr,len){
  alert(len);
  alert(arr);
}
 </script>
 <button type="button" onclick="f1()">Click Me!</button> 
 </body>
```

It means that if you declare first your javascript code when the browser interpretes, it'll be able to find your function.

```html
 <body>
 <script>
 function f1(){
 var str = "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff";
 var strArr = str.split(",");
 f2(strArr,strArr.length);
}

function f2(arr,len){
  alert(len);
  alert(arr);
}
 </script>
 <button type="button" onclick="f1()">Click Me!</button> 
 </body>
```